# How can I find out where a click event gets caught?

Tags: javascript, html, events, click

I am working on a very complex website and i have a piece of HTML on the page inside which no button is clickable. I think the click event gets caught somewhere so that the click handlers of the buttons do not fire.

**How can I find out where those click events gets caught?**

Comment: Can we see the js/html code? (or a snippet of it) Maybe make a fiddle?

Comment: Have you verified you don't have a transparent element shadowing all other elements?

Comment: Are you sure that JavaSscript is enabled and that you are not getting an error in your JavaScript code?

Comment: @jalynn2: yes, it is enabled and i get no errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a click event listener to the document, and see what's catching the event:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
})
```

Comment: No, this is not what i am looking for. This way i do get the clicked html element, but this doen't help me find the piece of code where the click events propagation gets stopped.

Comment: @Thariama: In that case, it might be an idea to have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node), and use my code to check what element you should inspect.

Comment: i am using the Visul Event bookmarklet already since several months. Tried it here, but i have not been able to detect the desired click event handler

Comment: Then my last suggestion would be to add a [breakpoint in your JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints), and try to see if you can find the function responsible.

Comment: found out the source to my problem has been soemwhere else 
(there was no stopping of the propagation, but an overlying html elment that prevented the desired element to be clicked). i will accept this answer because it is the solution to the problem in case an event intercepts/stops propagation

Comment: You could have found that by using Firebug inspect.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `event.target` of the click event to see where it is.

Comment: For that, you have to add an event handler to the clicked element. The OP wants to know where to add that event handler.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `document.click()` or `document.live("click",...)` handler somewhere in the javascript included in the page, which returns `false`.

Comment: correct, now i would like to get to know how i can find it in a complex page with lots of included javascript files

Comment: Use "find" in "Firebug" or "Chrome JS console".

Comment: find? - how do i use this?

Comment: Open the website in Firefox. Open Firebug. Click on `HTML`, press `Ctrl + F`. Search dialog will pop-up, search for "click". This will get you any inline javascript code. Else click on `Script` and do search again.

Comment: In Chrome, press `Ctrl + Shift + J` to open JS Console. Click `Sources` and press `Ctrl + F`.

Comment: well, thanks for that info...but this function is nothing new to me (+1 for your effort)